# Problema no Modal

Tags: php, javascript

Estou com uma tabela do meu modal e queria que se o usuário clicar tanto em Código quanto em Descrição inserisse somente o Código no meu `input`, porém estou tentando e sem sucesso, pois ao clicar em qualquer linha da coluna Descrição é inserido todos os Códigos no campo `input`

index.php

```
<div class="container">
        <h2>Modal</h2>
        <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Unidade</button>
                <input type="text" class="form-control unidade">
                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                    <label class="modal-title">UNIDADE - clique sobre a unidade desejada</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <table id="get-value" border="2">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>  Unidade  </th>
                                                <th>  Descrição</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        <?php
                                              include ("conn.php");

                                                $result = "SELECT codigo, descricao FROM cadunid";
                                                $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $result);


                                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){

                                                    echo "<tr>";
                                                        echo "<td class='btn-default get-value'>  ". $row['codigo'] ."  </td>";
                                                        echo "<td class='btn-default get-value-codigo'>  ". $row['descricao'] ."  </td>";
                                                    echo "</tr>";
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                    </table>

                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    $(document).on('click', '.get-value', function() {
        var value = $(this).text();
        $('.close').trigger('click');
        $('.unidade').val(value);
    });


    $(document).on('click', '.get-value-codigo', function() {
        var value = $('.get-value').text();
        $('.close').trigger('click');
        $('.unidade').val(value);
    });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em relação ao código:

```
$(document).on('click', '.get-value-codigo', function() {
    var value = $('.get-value').text();
    $('.close').trigger('click');
    $('.unidade').val(value);
});
```

A variável value está pegando o texto de todos os elementos `.get-value`. O que é necessário é restringir essa consulta apenas aos "siblings" (elementos lado a lado).

Tente, por exemplo:

```
$(document).on('click', '.get-value-codigo', function() {
    var value = $(this).siblings('.get-value').text();
    $('.close').trigger('click');
    $('.unidade').val(value);
});
```

Comment: consegui, obrigado cara. Mas pode tirar uma dúvida minha que surgiu? Se eu tiver uma tabela com 6 elementos, eu teria um jeito mais simples do que fazer 6 scripts apontando para o elemento que eu quero que preencha o input ?

Comment: Esse código que te passei tu escreveu 6 vezes? Se fizer usando caminhos relativos (parent, siblings, children, etc.), é possível fazer de forma genérica, sem precisar repetir 6 vezes

Comment: não neste caso eu só tenho dois campos então só utilizei no campo abaixo que era referente a coluna descrição, mas se eu tiver 6 colunas e que seja necessário que ao clicar em qualquer linha referente ao código do cliente insira o código do cliente no input entende

Comment: Sim, nesse caso você pode colocar a mesma classe (get-value-codigo) em todas as colunas e o código vai automaticamente pegar o valor da coluna com classe get-value, sem necessidade de replicar o script

Comment: obrigado realmente ajudou muito